# HTML and CSS Background image in a specific section

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to get an image to fill a specific section on the web page I'm making but I cannot find anything that works online.

```css
.bigslide {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  /*background: rgb(231, 231, 231);*/
  padding: 160px 0;
  color: #0ed1fb;
  animation: slideleft 2000s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: slideleft infinite linear;
}

.bigslide h1 {
  font-size: 34px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.bigslide p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="bigslide">
  <div class="bigslide">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="slideup">Tigercraft01's High Quality Setups</h1>
      <p>Scroll down to read about me and what I do.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I need the image to show behind the text that loads with the snippet provided.

Comment: its the same picture twice. and i rather had some fiddle or similar

Comment: Apart from the fact that your supposed HTML image shows CSS code as well ... please go read [ask], and then use primarily your _words_ to describe what the problem you are trying to solve is. Only showing pictures is not enough here.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve], preferably as a [live demo](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). Don't show pictures of code.

Comment: Please post code instead of pictures of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why it isn't in your CSS since you're trying to add an image but if you want to add a background image to your section, just use :

```
.bigslide {
    background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/g/500/500/');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```